# stored procedure return return more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_checktime]
( @Booking_Date date ,
    @Stime time(7) ,
    @Etime time(7) ,
    @Room varchar(50),
    @res int output
 )
AS
BEGIN
IF (@Stime=(select Start_Time from Booking_master where Booking_Date=@Booking_Date and Room=@Room) or @Stime>=(select Start_Time from Booking_master) and @Stime<=(select End_Time from Booking_master where Booking_Date=@Booking_Date and Room=@Room))
BEGIN
        set @res=0
END

ELSE    
    BEGIN
        set @res=1
    END

END
```

when excuting this procedure it reurns (Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Add top 1 in your subquery.

Comment: do you mean IF(EXISTS(your query))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause to your problem is this statement:

```
@Stime=(select Start_Time from Booking_master where Booking_Date=@Booking_Date and Room=@Room)
```

The subquery seems to return more than one row.  The "reflexive" fix is to replace it with `in`:

```
@Stime in (select Start_Time from Booking_master where Booking_Date=@Booking_Date and Room=@Room)
```

In your case, I think you are better off fixing the logic so you only have one `if (exists . . .)` statement.  Something like:

```
if (exists (select 1
            from Booking_master bm
            where Booking_Date = @Booking_Date and Room = @Room and
                  (@Stime = Start_Time or
                   (@Stime >= StartTime and @Stime <= EndTime)
                  )
           )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are only allowed one result.  Try adding TOP 1 to each of your subqueries, though the problem is likely isolated to your second subquery.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_checktime]
( @Booking_Date date ,
    @Stime time(7) ,
    @Etime time(7) ,
    @Room varchar(50),
    @res int output
 )
AS
BEGIN
IF (
    @Stime = (select Top 1 Start_Time 
              from Booking_master 
              where Booking_Date=@Booking_Date and Room=@Room) 
 or @Stime >= (select Top 1 Start_Time 
               from Booking_master) 
and @Stime <= (select Top 1 End_Time 
               from Booking_master 
               where Booking_Date=@Booking_Date and Room=@Room))
BEGIN
        set @res=0
END

ELSE    
    BEGIN
        set @res=1
    END

END
```